# How can I compare multiple value of Keys in the same dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

**Application:** we are working in a sector where our product can have hundreds of different properties. And when we have to do an offer for tens products, this app could help us to reduce the number of offers by gathering products with the same configuration

**How it works:** user gives the properties in the entries and the application will compare them to see if some configurations are the same (Here configuration = "Config 0", or "Config 1" and so on ...).

The configurations and the given properties should be put in a dictionary-like {Config 1:[1800,1,1500,x...], Config 2:[2000,2,1600,x...], Config n:[x,y,o,x...]} The program will compare the values list of the keys and try to if some values list are the same.

**Problem:** I have not managed to compare the values of the dictionnary to know if there are keys with the same values

How can I solve this problem?

The button 'Launch' enables to launch of the comparison

```
import os
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk


data_list=['Name','Q','Speed','TH','Open through','Level','Accesses','CW','CD','CH','SW','SD','Headroom','SP','Door type','DW','DH']
list_excel=[]
dict_user_entries={}
dict_redundance={}

fenetre =Tk()
fenetre.geometry('800x750')
a = 5
nbofconfig=4

def comparison():
    dict_redundance={}
    for r in range(len(dict_user_entries)):
        for o in range(len(dict_user_entries)):
            if dict_user_entries['Config '+str(r)] == dict_user_entries['Config '+str(o)]: #---  We compare if the values of the compared keys are the same
                print('yes -- Config ',str(r),' = Config ',str(o))
                if  'Config '+str(o) in dict_redundance:
                    dict_redundance['Config '+str(o)].append('Config '+str(r))
                else:
                    dict_redundance['Config '+str(o)]=['Config '+str(r)]
                
            else:
                print('no -- Config ',str(r),' =x= Config ',str(o))
                
    #----- print
    for i in dict_redundance.keys():
        print(i)
        
            

    
cadrebouton=Frame(fenetre)
cadrebouton.pack(side=TOP,anchor=NW)
boutonexcel=Button(cadrebouton,text="Load Excel File",width=15,height=1,bg="white",bd=5, command=excel_load)
boutonexcel.pack(side=LEFT, anchor =NW)
boutontest=Button(cadrebouton,text="Test",width=15,height=1,bg="white",bd=5, command=test)
boutontest.pack(side=LEFT, anchor =NW)
boutonlaunch=Button(cadrebouton,text="Launch",width=15,height=1,bg="white",bd=5, command=comparison)
boutonlaunch.pack(side=LEFT, anchor =NW)

head_frame=Frame(fenetre)
head_frame.pack(side=TOP,anchor=NW)

head_label=Label(head_frame,text='Data',width=15)
head_label.pack(side=LEFT)

for i in range(nbofconfig):
    head_config=Label(head_frame,text='Config '+str(i), width=13)
    head_config.pack(side=LEFT)


cadre_global=Frame(fenetre)
cadre_global.pack(side=TOP,anchor=NW)

cadre_global2=Frame(cadre_global)
cadre_global2.pack(side=LEFT)


for x in range(a):
    frame=Frame(cadre_global2)
    frame.pack(side=TOP,anchor=NW)
    
    label_data=Label(frame,width=15,text=data_list[x])
    label_data.pack(side=LEFT)
    
cadre_global3=Frame(cadre_global)
cadre_global3.pack(side=LEFT)
bx=0#------Test, to delete



    
for i in range(nbofconfig):

    frame2=Frame(cadre_global3)
    frame2.pack(side=LEFT)
    dict_user_entries['Config '+str(i)]=[]
    for x in range(a):
        bx+=x
        var_entry=StringVar()
        my_entry=Entry(frame2,textvariable=var_entry, width=15,bd=2) #--- Users gives the property
        my_entry.insert(0,bx)
        my_entry.pack()
        dict_user_entries['Config '+str(i)].append(my_entry) #--- Data from user will stored in the dictionnary
     
    
fenetre.mainloop()

os.system('pause')
```

Here an example:
[image]
[image]

Thank you !

**EDIT 11.05.2021:** I found the solution. Juste put the keys and values from dict_user_entries with .get() in a new dictionary.

```
def comparison():
    list_values=[]
    dict_2={}
    dict_reference={}
    dict_final={}
    
    #---- We put the data of entries in a new dictionnary
    index_1=0
    for keys in dict_user_entries.keys():
        dict_2[list_name[index_1].get()]=[]
        for i in range(a):
            dict_2[list_name[index_1].get()].append(dict_user_entries[keys][i].get()) 
        index_1+=1
    
    #---- We stored value in a list to count the number of different configurations (len(list_values)) and create intermediate dictionaries
    index=0
    for keys in dict_2.keys():
        if dict_2[keys] in list_values:
            pass
        else:
            list_values.append(dict_2[keys])
            dict_reference['Config '+str(index)]=dict_2[keys]
            dict_final['Config '+str(index)]=[]
            index+=1
            
    #---- We create the unique configurations with their datas
    index_2=0
    for keys in dict_2.keys():
        for i in dict_reference.keys():
            if dict_2[keys] == dict_reference[i]:
                dict_final[i].append(list_name[index_2].get())
            else:
                pass
        index_2+=1        
                
    #----- print
    for keys in dict_final.keys():
        print('\n',keys,' = ',dict_reference[keys],' = ', dict_final[keys])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like what you are comparing is a list of tkinter entry instances. What you need to do is extract the value from the entry, and then compare the values. You cannot do a comparison on an entire list, because what you are comparing is the list object itself, not the values.

Replace this line:

```
if dict_user_entries['Config '+str(r)] == dict_user_entries['Config '+str(o)]:
```

With this:

```
list_a = [x.get() for x in dict_user_entries['Config '+str(r)]]
list_b = [x.get() for x in dict_user_entries['Config '+str(o)]]
if all([list_a[i] == list_b[i] for i in range(len(list_a))]):
```

Comment: Hi, thank you. I already edited my post a few minutes before yours with a similar solution. You re right ! I just extracted the value (.get()) of the entries and put them in a new dictionary. The application works now after many tests perfectly :)